# Detect external keyboard events iOS using IOHID framework

Tags: ios, keypress

Can any one please tell whether it is allowed to use IOHID framework in iOS to detect external keyboard events. UIKeyCommand doesn't support keyUp and keydown events and it doesn't allow to register for some of the keys like eg: delete, insert, home, pgup, pgdown etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That framework is not available for use on iOS

Comment: Thank you Paul. So there is no way other than using UIKeyCommand? But that doesn't support full functionality.